# Wrong headings diplaying on contact search results

Tags: wordpress, search

Using CiviCRM version 4.7.20 on WordPress 4.8 the headings are wrong on the results of Find Contacts and also Advanced Find. They are all shifted three places to the left, cyclically. The links on the headings match their names.

I've added a few custom fields and profiles, but not changed any code.

Very odd and looks like I'll have to reinstall it all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was i believe fixed in 4.7.21 See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20644

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... I look forward to trying 4.7.21 but at the moment it won't install for me. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19380/cannot-install-civicrm-4-7-21-on-wordpress-drupal

Comment: I never got 4.7.21 working, but can confirm that it has been resolved in 4.7.22